# Alamofire: How to get parts of response JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode6, alamofire

I have a question about Alamofire.

I'm doing this:

```
var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
        mutableURLRequest.setValue(response!.allHeaderFields["TOKEN"] as! String, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-TOKEN")
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance // or create a new one
        let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)
        request.responseJSON { (request, response, string, error) in
            println(response!.statusCode)
            println(string!)

        }
```

When I print string the output is JSON. I want to search for a single element (f.e. username or something else) in that JSON response.

How can I do that?

Thank you and best regards,

Alban Veliu

Comment: After @Glenn told me about SwiftyJSON here I have an example:

var jsonString = JSON(string!)
jsonString["username"]

jsonString["username"] returns me the username "admin" which is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Swift, but IMHO it's a lot easier using the SwiftyJSON framework. It has an excellent tutorial and documentation and you should be up an running in no time : https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Tank you very much. SwiftyJSON is amazing!